# MySQL: Total count of points based on weekly vote

Tags: mysql, count

So I have this weekly vote for best players of the game. Users can vote for 3 best players, 1st gets 3 points, 2nd 2p and 3rd 1p. So it would be easy just to count all votes of all games and figure out who is the best. But the number of votes per game can be significantly different.

For example:

Vote1:

1st: 100 of total 500 votes -> 20%

Vote2:

1st: 40 of total 100 votes -> 40%

So I would want to count all votes of all games so that every game is equally important. Basically I think I just need to count percentage of votes per game and sum then together. But how can I achieve this easily?

My table is like this:

id, game_id, player3, player2, player1

Comment: Your table is like that and what is player3, player2 and player1 ? the player name or id ? the amount of votes they got ? how are u going to calculate it weekly based if u don't have a date field ? Please do provide more information.

Comment: Sorry for that. Player3, player2, and player1 are player id's. Player3 3points, player2 2points and player1 1point. Didn't mean weekly as strictly as that. It's more like a weekly game. So I can calculate every game totals based on game_id

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `UNION ALL` to put all your players together (if I'm understanding your question correctly) -- not completely sure of your desired results, so have just left like this for now.

```
select player_id, sum(points)
from (
  select player3 player_id, 3 points
  from games
  union all
  select player2, 2 
  from games
  union all
  select player1, 1 
  from games
) t
group by player_id
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2b0a1/2)

Comment: Thanks but that only calculates points in the "normal" way. So that total vote count per game doesn't matter. I need a way to calculate that 1 vote in a game with 3 votes is more important than 100 votes in a game with 500 votes.

Comment: @mikeykk -- not sure I'm understanding.  Can you update the fiddle with sample data and desired results?

Comment: @mikeykk -- something more on the lines of this maybe? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6dcc/4

Comment: Thanks but not really. I updatet your first fiddle to make it easier to understand http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5f98/1 <-- This is what I'm after: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62375224/results.txt

Comment: @mikeykk -- the inner query is returning what you want -- combined that in a subquery and summed the amts: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5f98/10

Comment: Yeah, it seems to work just right with those 3 players. But with more than 3 it doesn't work.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d60aab/1